# Hilbert space compression of CAT(0) groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

> Does there exist a CAT(0) group with Hilbert space compression $<1$?

The *Hilbert space compression* of a metric space $(X,d)$, e.g. a group endowed with the word metric given by a finite generating set, is the supremum of the numbers $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that there exists a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, positive constants $C_1,C_2$ and a map $f : X \to \mathcal{H}$ with
$$C_1 \cdot d(x, y)^\alpha \leq \| f(x) − f(y) \| \leq C_2 \cdot d(x, y)$$
for all $x, y \in X$.

It is known that finite-dimensional CAT(0) cube complexes have Hilbert space compression $1$, so the answer is negative among groups acting geometrically on CAT(0) cube complexes; and more generally among groups acting on CAT(0) cube complexes with quasi-isometrically embedded orbits (which include, for instance, Coxeter groups, even though they may not be cocompactly cubulable). All the examples I know of finitely generated groups with Hilbert space compression $<1$ (e.g. wreath products and Thompson groups) are rather far from the family of CAT(0) groups.

I suspect that the question is open, but maybe I am missing some recent results?

Comment: Any idea if the 4-strand braid group has Hilbert space compression $<1$? That's CAT(0) but not CAT(0) cubical, so that strikes me as the most straightforward candidate. (I'm sure you've already thought of this, but, can't hurt to ask.)

Comment: No idea... The Hilbertian geometry of braid groups seems to be rather mysterious. For instance, I think we still don't know whether they are a-T-menable. But we know that they coarsely embed in Hilbert spaces since they have finite asymptotic dimension.